# Do characters like 司, 习, and 可 have different first strokes?

Tags: handwriting

I'm interested in the first stroke of characters like 司, 习, and 可.  This is how it looks on my computer (but I don't know if this is a matter of fonts):

- 可 starts off with a single horizontal stroke, whereas
- 司 and 习 do not (it starts off horizontal, then proceeds downwards, then hooks).

My handwriting of 可以, 学习, and 司机 (where I've deliberately used the two "styles"):

[image: 可以, 学习, and 司机]

I'm not sure if it's simply wrong to write this, or if they're acceptable alternatives.

**Question**: Do characters like 司, 习, and 可 have different first strokes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure if it's simply wrong to write this, or if they're acceptable alternatives.

It's simply wrong. 横折勾 does not equal to 横 + 竖折勾. Even in artistic or decorative writing, they are clearly distinguished for the most of the time.

The answers about stroke order (笔顺) are not what was asked here.

Answer (score 2):

We can use [zdic](http://www.zdic.net)'s 笔顺 for this:

[司](http://www.zdic.net/z/16/js/53F8.htm)

> フ一丨フ一

[习](http://www.zdic.net/z/15/js/4E60.htm)

> フ丶一

[可](http://www.zdic.net/z/16/js/53EF.htm)

> 一丨フ一丨

So technically 司 and 习 begin with a 折 stroke, while 可 begins with a 横 stroke.

笔顺 works like:

笔顺名称    一（横）    丨（竖）    丿（撇）    丶（点）    乛（折）

笔顺编号    1   2   3   4   5

Answer (score 0):

The link has been provided to you for your reference in another answer.

However, there is a generic rule which I think it's good for you to know.

This is the one from the web:

> 新编笔顺规则歌诀

从上到下为主，从左到右为辅。

中央凸出先写，右上有点后补。

横竖交叉先横，撇捺交叉捺收。

上包下时先外，下包上时先内。

三框首横末折，大口后封底部。

多重复合结构，根据层次分组。

特殊不合规则，源于从草从古。

熟记规则特例，笔画正确无误。

写字流畅美观，检字准确迅速。

I personally:

先上后下， 先左后右, 先中间后两边， ...